# Problema con jQuery y eventos MouseEnter y MouseLeave

Tags: javascript, jquery

quisiera que por medio de jQuery utilizar el mouseenter y mouseleave y cambie de imagenes en la card. El code q de JS y no estaría funcionando.

[Codigo de HTML]

```
    <div class="card jugadores" id="imgplayers">  
        <img src="../img/2016/leonTomeo.jpeg"class="card-img-top cambio" alt="">
          <div class="card-body">
          <h6 class="card-title">Nombre: León Tomeo</h6>
          <ul class="card-text" >
            <li>Posición: Central</li>
            <li>Camiseta: 15</li>
            <li>Altura: 1,40 cm</li>
        </div>
```

Código JS

```
$(document).ready(inicio());

function inicio() {
  $("#imgplayers").mouseenter(cambiarImg());
  $("#imgplayers").mouseleave(originalImg());
}

function cambiarImg() {
  $("#imgplayers").src = '../img/2016/leonTomeo2.jpeg';
  console.log("cambiar", cambiarImg);
}

function originalImg() {
  $("#imgplayers").src = '../img/2016/leonTomeo.jpeg';
  console.log("original", originalImg);
}
```

Como les muestro el código que tengo de JS con jquery no me estaría funcionando, los console.log se imprimen solamente cuando de inicia la página o se renderiza, luego cuando paso el mouse no vuelve a imprimir, además no me cambia la imagen cuando retiro el mouse de la card.

Comment: TODO el código a texto por favor. Quita esa "imagen bonita" y coloca el HTML a texto.

Comment: Ya lo pasé a código, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás seleccionando mal la imagen. `imgplayers` es el div, no es la imagen. Por otro lado, usa `.attr`. Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(inicio());

function inicio() {
  $("#imgplayers").mouseenter(cambiarImg);
  $("#imgplayers").mouseleave(originalImg);
}

function cambiarImg() {
  $("#imgplayers img").attr("src",'https://picsum.photos/200/200');
}

function originalImg() {
  $("#imgplayers img").attr("src",'https://picsum.photos/200/201')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card jugadores" id="imgplayers">  
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/201" class="card-img-top cambio" alt="">
  <div class="card-body">
  <h6 class="card-title">Nombre: León Tomeo</h6>
  <ul class="card-text" >
    <li>Posición: Central</li>
    <li>Camiseta: 15</li>
    <li>Altura: 1,40 cm</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Jaime, esta respuesta la vi en otra consulta por stack, el tema que en el src trae un link https....., pero con las fotos desde una carpeta de img desde mi pc no funciona. Lo bueno que si le tiras un console.log tanto del mouse leave como de mouse enter funciona

Comment: @Fedef11980 entonces tendras algun problema con la ruta de esa carpeta **img**... es decir, si con referencias absolutas a imágenes como las de esta respuesta te funciona bien, y no con las tuyas, **ha de ser por la ruta o los nombres de archivos** que les estas poniendo, que o bien está mal, o bien no tienes los permisos debidos y no te deja acceder a esos contenidos.

Comment: Solucionado!!! Era la extensión de la foto que una es jpg y la otra jpeg, Muchas gracias Jaime y masterguru!! Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Usando jQuery modifique un poco tu código, y que do así.

Es cuestión de entender el funcionamiento, aunque realice más cambios, prueba de la siguiente manera.

En un `let` defini la dirección URL de la imagen, lo cual se llama mediante un atributo (`attr`) en la misma posición (`this`) de evento de la función.

```js
$(document).ready( function() { 
 
 let imagen1 = "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any";
 let imagen2 = "https://placeimg.com/1000/480/animals";
 
 $("#imgplayers").on("mouseenter", function() {

  $(this).find("img").attr("src", imagen1); 

 }).on("mouseleave", function() { 

  $(this).find("img").attr("src", imagen2); 

 });
 
});
```

```html
<div class="card jugadores" id="imgplayers"> 
   
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/480/animals" class="card-img-top cambio" alt=""> 
   
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Me imprime en consola lo siguiente 

cambiar function cambiarImg()
    arguments: null
​    caller: null
​    length: 0
​    name: "cambiarImg"
​    prototype: Object { … }
​    <prototype>: function ()

Pero no me cambia la imagen

Comment: Por otro lado el  console.log de OriginalImg no se imprime